# How can i use list results for further calculations

Tags: common-lisp

as a lisp newbie i'm stuck with a general problem: I want to query data, generate a sum over it and want to calculate further with this results.

For example i sum up 33 77 and want to divide the result:

```
(defun sum (L)
  (reduce '+ L))
(/ 999 (sum '(33 77)))
```

Without the divison i receive the correct sum. When i'm trying to proceed further, i get an error that a numerical function was given an argument.

A type-of query `(type-of '(sum '(33 77)))` says it's CONS

What's the correct handling for results for further calculation?

Comment: Regarding “an error that a numerical function was given an argument”: I do not think that this is the actual error message.  The code as shown works as intended.   Can you show what you actually run, and what you actually got?

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'm using an building simulation software (IDA ICE) with an integrated common lisp interpreter. There it isn't working, no i checked it with gnu common lisp, where it's working. Seems to be an specific interpretation of that software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(type-of '(sum '(33 77)))
```

The evaluation of the above consists first in evaluating `'(sum '(33 77))`, and call function `type-of` with the result of the evaluation.

`'(sum '(33 77))` is the same as `(quote (sum (quote (33 77))))`, except that the apostrophe is a reader syntax `'` that turns what follows, say `x`, into `(quote x)`.

The `quote` form is self-evaluating, meaning the value it evaluates to is the exact value that was quoted, here `(sum '(33 77))`.

That value is data representing code: it literally is a list, built at read-time, that contains the symbol `sum` followed by another element, a list whose first element is `quote` that is followed by another list containing 33 and 77, literal numbers.

Since the value of your expression is a list, and since lists are built by chaining cons-cells, it is normal that `type-of` returns `cons`.

If you remove one level of quotes:

```
(type-of (sum '(33 77)))
```

Then the evaluation of `(sum '(33 77))` follows the normal evaluation of function calls, by first evaluating the argument, `'(33 77)`, a literal list, and calling `sum` with it. Your function returns the sum, 110, and this is the value that is given when calling `type-of`. In that case, you should obtain a numerical type.

Comment: If i remove the outer quotes i get the same error like when i try to divide the results of the sum: A numeric function was given an argument

Comment: @FloydP Please double-check, as far as I know the code you described should work: https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/18jJTWtNE@huDRXQcNHU0GjKDWlNDlVQV1bwUdTk0ujoCgzr0RBAyStrmFsrGBurokkXFJZkKqbn4Yur/n/PwA